# Generic or better yet custom message of the day in Oracle sql plus

Tags: oracle

I'm trying to create a message of the day type notification when users login to sqlplus.

Currently I use the login.sql to add a dbms_application_info and set a module and action for the message.  This has limitations so I was wondering if Oracle has anything like a MOTD feature. Or maybe someone has created their own solution.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There's no way of doing this. You can't even use DBMS_OUTPUT and a login trigger, as it all gets fired before sqlplus is ready for it.

Comment: what limitations?

Answer (score 1):

Anything like this?

```
$ cat $ORACLE_HOME/sqlplus/admin/glogin.sql
set serveroutput on feedback off
exec dbms_output.put_line('******************');
exec dbms_output.put_line('MESSAGE OF THE DAY');
exec dbms_output.put_line('******************');
set serveroutput off feedback on
```

Logging in:

```
$ sqlplus test/test

SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.4.0 Production on Sun Jan 26 00:49:29 2014

Copyright (c) 1982, 2013, Oracle.  All rights reserved.


Connected to:
Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.4.0 - 64bit Production
With the Partitioning, OLAP, Data Mining and Real Application Testing options

******************
MESSAGE OF THE DAY
******************
SQL>
```

Comment: He said he didn't want to use login.sql?